# Angular 2: how to use a custom pipe in component logic code, not in template

Tags: angular, ionic2

I used to create custom filters with ionic 1 (angularjs) and then use them either in the template `{{data | customfilter }}` or in the controller `str = $filter('customfilter')(data);`.

Now I just created a pipe with angular 2, but how to use it in the typescript code ?

Thanks

src/pipes/nospace.ts:

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'nospace'
})
export class Nospace {
  transform(value, args) {
    return (!value) ? '' : value.replace(/ /g, '');
  }
}
```

src/pages/page.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Nospace} from '../../pipes/nospace';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
  pipes: [Nospace]
})
export class HomePage {

  myString: any;

  constructor() {
    this.myString = "Pipes are super cool";
    //I want to use the pipe here !
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Angular Concepts Repository. Please check that if gives a very simple idea of how to use pipes and also has a working demo.

```
import { SquarePipe } from './square.pipe';

describe('SquarePipe', () => {

  let pipe :SquarePipe;

  beforeEach(() => {
    pipe = new SquarePipe();
  });

  it('transforms 2 to 4', () => {
    let value: any = 2;
    expect(pipe.transform(value)).toEqual(4);
  });

});
```

Check this link for more info [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/pipes)

Comment: The second link doesn't work
The first one doesn't show example of usage for pipes in typescript code

Comment: @Louis As the page is deployed in gh-pages the link was incorrect please check now the second link

Comment: Ok I see you edit, but that doesn't answer my question. Can you give the equivalent code of $filter()

Comment: @Louis i am not able to figure out what do you mean by ts code ?

Comment: Typescript code, I want to use the filter in the component (not the template)

Comment: I added some code from a test in one of the links.  It's `pipe.transform(value)`

Comment: What I am asking is exactly the same feature as $filter in Angular 1, but in Angular 2

Comment: @Louis its more like a method that takes a value and changes to give a different value when you use directly in the Component, where as in templates Pipes just change the value that is to be rendered in the view.
you can initialize the class and use it in any component

Answer (score 0):

See [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/pk46dQIaKQRxjwFdDm2r) for what Rahul Singh was referring to by using the pipe directly inside the component using your `nospace.ts`:

**app.ts**

```
//our root app component
import { Component, NgModule, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Nospace } from '../nospace';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Original: {{name}}</h2>
      <h2>No spaces: {{nameNospace}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name: string;
  nameNospace: string;
  noSpaceTransform: Nospace = new Nospace();

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Plunker! v${VERSION.full}`;
    this.nameNospace = this.noSpaceTransform.transform(this.name);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [App],
  bootstrap: [App],
})
export class AppModule {}
```